# install "sub package" Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pip, jupyter

I am struggling to install packages, and "sub-packages" in Jupyter Notebook; I suspect I am missing some of the basic concepts around installing packages.

I understand that to install a package within the notebook I use

```
! pip install --user <package>
```

What I don't understand is how to install a "sub-package" (feel free to advise what the correct terminology is)  such as below.

```
 from nltk.tagger import *
```

Here is the [original script](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.pitt.edu/projects/nltk/docs/tutorial/chunking/nochunks.html) that this comes from:

If i try :

```
 !pip install nltk.tagger
```

I get the following error information / error

```
Collecting nltk.tagger
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nltk.tagger (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for nltk.tagger
```

So my first question is. How do I install this nltk.tagger subpackage? Also if tagger is a sub-package of NLTK, how come it isn't installed when I do a pip install NLTK?

Although the error mentions a version, searching online I can't find a reference even to the subpackage "tagger". Any advice or links explaining this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you `pip inslall nltk`, the subpackage `nltk.tagger`, and other dependencies will be installed too.

This is generally true for all packages.